# Selection with Shift_RMB

Tags: select

I'm new in Blender 3.0, but I used to work with 2.7 a lot.
I try to select a couple of objects in object mode with shift and right mouse button. When first object is selected and I want to select next one with pressed shift and clicking RMB always blender select object far behind that one I wanted. Not this one which is closest and visible but covered object behind. I hope you get what I mean. Is it any chance to change the order of selecting objects?
Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing an image, but you should be able to select objects in sequence by clicking again. Each click should select the next object "down the stack".

Comment: It is as You say, but clicking a lot to select object through the stack is annoying. Right now I'm modelling interior of the car, and if I want to select some part of interior like steering wheel, then blender highlights some part of car body which is behing wheel. Its unintuitive.
image:
https://imgupload.pl/zdjecie/SwleJ

Comment: You could always select the object closer to you and then hit H to hide it first. Then ALT-H to unhide it again when you've finished.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but when You work for a few hours with project, you want to do things as fast and simple as it possible. Hiding and unhide looks like adding a few unnecessary steps. But thank You for giving me ideas :)